# cannot install ws@0.4.31 while installing socket.io on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I use node.js ver 10.0.28 and I installed socket.io with "npm install socket.io", but it gets stuck at this point.

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/proton/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log || (exit 0)

Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Show the relevant part of error log.

Comment: it was not error, it just gets stuck

Comment: Try leaving it for a while. Not sure but looks like system related. But let the command complete.